# How can I get if a checkbox inside a table is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a checkbox element in a table and cannot figure out how to check if it is checked.

This code `row.find("td:eq(6)").children().html()` returns the html of the checkbox, however when I try and use `row.find("td:eq(6)").children().is(":checked")` it always returns false.

I'm not sure if you can return whether the checkbox is checked like this however the .html() function used previously returns the ID with it, so if I could pull this checkbox elements ID seperately then I could use that to find if the checkbox is checked like that? However, I'm not sure how to pull the ID from the html...

Thanks

Comment: Show your html for a table row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use find selector again, find input type checkbox, and check if it is checked.

```
row.find("td:eq(6)").find("[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect whether a checkbox is checked, give it an ID, then have an onclick function to determine whether is checked. Eg:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test_check" id="test_check" onclick="detectCheckBox()" value="Yes">
```

Now in your javascript have a function like:

```
function detectCheckBox(){
  if (document.getElementById('test_check').checked) {
   //It is checked
   alert("Checkbox Checked");
  }
}
```